# Method invocation in Swift: issue with beta (Xcode 6-b6)

Tags: ios, swift

I have two methods, if I call one from the other, I will get an exception (sigabort on my AppDelegate), if I however merge the two it works fine. It used to work fine b.t.w. under beta 5, but it might be not a bug, but caused by a programming error on which beta 5 was just not picky enough of course:

```
func getClientInfo(MyBeacon: CLBeacon) {

    let majorID  = MyBeacon.major
    let minorID  = MyBeacon.minor


    // create some JSON data and configure the request
    let jsonString1 = "{\"major\":\""
    let jsonString2 = "\",\"minor\":\""
    let jsonString3 = "\"}"

    var jsonString = jsonString1
    jsonString += majorID.stringValue
    jsonString += jsonString2
    jsonString += minorID.stringValue
    jsonString += jsonString3

    var json = jsonString

    //self.getClientInfo(jsonString) // issue here!
//}  

//func getClientInfo(json: String) {
 let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession() // breakpoint here

 var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.myserver.com/getbeaconid.php"), cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?
  ... // do something with results etc...

}
```

so if I uncomment the line of "// issue here!" and the three lines below, I get the exception, if I merge the two functions it works very well! I even don't go to the breakpoint at the first line of the second method in the case of two separate methods. Note: the strange thing I do with "jsconString1 ... " is because otherwise I get another issue, Swift doesn't seem to like to concatenate to many values at ones, but this workaround goes fine.

Comment: What is the error / issue Xcode is pointing at in the debugger? Can you provide us the text it displays?

Comment: what does the stack trace look like?